# MySQL values limit to 1 and 0

Tags: mysql

Hello guys I'm just a newbie so sorry for my question :)

I already tried using char, tinyint, bool and CHECK constraint.

Here's my CHECK constraint:

```
CHECK (user_type>=0 AND user_type<=1)
```

But still I can insert values more than 1, all I want is just 1s and 0s.
I'll use it as type of my users.
Although I can validate this in front-end level, I still want do it in a database itself.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414421/does-my-sql-supports-check-constraint

Comment: Thanks guys for your warm replies :) appreciate it much. But I think i'll stick on the simpliest one `If you really want to do it you can create a table containing the values 0 and 1 and set up a foreign key constraint.` from Sir Mark. Thanks again :)

Comment: strager - `INT` columns can contain values other than 0 and 1. The `(1)` only sets the display width; it doesn't constrain the values that may be stored. Even if it did constrain the values stored, though, you'd still be able to store 2 to 9.

Answer (score 4):

use `set` or `enum` as the colum type. then define the values (eg: 1,0) :)

Answer (score 3):

The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. [(Source)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

If you really want to do it you can create a table containing the values 0 and 1 and set up a foreign key constraint.

Comment: So what's your suggestion Sir Mark?

Comment: ahh ok, I think that would do it, thanks. 
Again, sorry for my question, I know its damn simple to you guys, still a student here, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that constraint to be enforced make a table boolconstants with those 2 values and use a foreign key constraint. Bit of a hack but works for all enum values :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's MySQL, wouldn't an enum column enforce the constraint as expected?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html